# How to use multiple tables in one model in yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have a product model that save information to product table in the DB, but i also have price table, color table and size table in my DB and on the form i will get all product information including price, size and color through product controller and product model, now i want to know how i can save the price, size and color on the form differently in there respective table. below is a snapshot

```
public function actionCreate(){
$data = \Yii::$app->request->post();
$model = new Product();
$model->title = $data['title'];
$model->name = $data['name'];
}
```

now how can i change this table name to price or size or color to be able to save `$data['size'] and $data['color'] and $data['price']` to there respective column

Comment: From your question's title `How to use...` the answer is using `use` :)

Answer (score 2):

One model is associated with one database table.

As for handling multiple models of different type, there is a good article in official docs - [Getting Data for Multiple Models](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-multiple-models.html).

Omitting the details, here is code snippet for controller:

```
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use app\models\User;
use app\models\Profile;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $user = User::findOne($id);
        if (!$user) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException("The user was not found.");
        }

        $profile = Profile::findOne($user->profile_id);

        if (!$profile) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException("The user has no profile.");
        }

        $user->scenario = 'update';
        $profile->scenario = 'update';

        if ($user->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $profile->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $isValid = $user->validate();
            $isValid = $profile->validate() && $isValid;
            if ($isValid) {
                $user->save(false);
                $profile->save(false);
                return $this->redirect(['user/view', 'id' => $id]);
            }
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'user' => $user,
            'profile' => $profile,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And for view:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'user-update-form',
    'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'],
]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($user, 'username') ?>

    ...other input fields...

    <?= $form->field($profile, 'website') ?>

    <?= Html::submitButton('Update', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

This article also might be useful - [Collecting tabular input](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-tabular-input.html). It covers collecting data from multiple models *of the same type*.

Also read [Models](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html) section, especially *Validation Rules* and *Massive Assignment* paragraphs. You should avoid handling `$_POST` parameters like that.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a model for each table. Insert the id of the product in price, color, and size tables. add product_id in all other tables. And try this:

```
    public function actionCreate()
{
    $data = \Yii::$app->request->post();
    $model = new Product();
    $model->title = $data['title'];
    $model->name = $data['name'];
    $model->save();
    $getlast=Yii::$app->db->getLastInsertId();

    $model = new Price();
    $model->price=Yii::$app->request->post('price');
    $model->product_id = $getlast;
    $model->save();

    $model = new Size();
    $model->size=Yii::$app->request->post('size');
    $model->product_id = $getlast;
    $model->save();
}
```

Comment: ok thank you guys for your idea i know i can do it this way but i was thinking maybe it's possible not to have model separately for color, sizes maybe i can just change the table name dynamically, but i think from all the answers i got it's nearly impossible so i need to create a model for each table